# Counting frequency of string or float in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, count, frequency

I have a list. Its pretty big. It has over 1 million entries. I want to count the frequency of each string in it. It stores numbers as strings from 1 to 1000. I have used the following but it keeps running for hours:

```
d = {b:a.count(b) for b in a}
n, m = d.keys(), d.values()
print n, m
```

Comment: The problem is that, to build that `dict`, you are doing `n` times(length of list `a`) an operation of cost `n`(`a.count(b)` has to iterate all `a` to search for `b`s). Which means it takes time proportional to `n^2` to build it. If you have a list of 1 million entries you have to do about `(10^6)^2 = 10^12` operations. Even if a single operation was a machine instruction it would take on the order of 10^3 seconds to build it. In reality it probably takes some (or at least)tens of machine instructions for each operation hence you'd have to wait hours/days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(a)

n, m = d.keys(), d.values()
print n, m
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case it's far easier to use a dictionary.
Insertion into a dictionary is really fast and retrieval from a dictionary is just as fast.

Here's a sample program that does exactly that:

```
import datetime
import random
def create_string(choice, size):
    str = ''
    for i in range(size):
         str = str + random.choice(choice)
    return str

def count_all(strings):
    count_dict = {}
    for i in strings:
        if i not in count_dict:
            count_dict[i] = 1
        else:
            count_dict[i] = count_dict[i] + 1
    return count_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_strings = []
    for i in range(1000000):
        all_strings.append(create_string(['a','b','c'], 4))

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    c_dict = count_all(all_strings)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print 'Took:', end - start
    print 'The count of aacc is ', c_dict['aacc']
```

And how does it fair?

```
./speed_test.py
Took: 0:00:00.219815
The count of aacc is  12317
```

Not bad at all, hey?
As an alternate option, to solve the problem mentioned by Ant, you want to get rid of the duplicates when doing the count. We can use a set for that:

```
d = {b:a.count(b) for b in set(a)}
```

According to my tests this isn't as fast as the dictionary method but less than a second so good enough.

Comment: Don't use `datetime` to profile performances. Use the `timeit` module(with iPython maybe), since it will take the average time correctly. If you want to do a single-shot benchmark use `time.perf_counter` if you are on python3.3+, since that's its purpose.

Comment: Right thanks, I did initially use timeit but since it's setup and code are passed in as strings, I thought it would make a unnecessarily complicated example.

Answer (score 1):

It is slow because you're running a.count for every string!

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'a']
```

then `str.count` will be called two times on 'a', and 1 time on 'b'.

Of course the second time on 'a' the result in the dictionary is just overridden so you don't even notice it

Use a default dict instead

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for obj in your_list:
    d[obj] += 1
```

or, again from the collections module, Counter http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects